# How can I measure file access performance (and volume) of a (Java) application

Tags: java, performance-testing

Given an application, how can I measure

- the amount of data read and written by that application?
- the time spent reading/writing to disk?

The specific application is Java-based (JBoss), and multi-threaded, and running as a service on Windows 7/2008 x64.

The overall goal I have is determining whether and why file access is a bottleneck in my application. Therefore, running the application in a defined and repeatable scenario is a given.

File access may be local as well as on network shares.

Windows performance monitor appears to be too hard to use (unless someone can point me to a helpful explanation).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Windows Performance Analyzer is the tool that can do (most of) what I need.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff191077%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can try [timeit](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17657), if I'm not mistaken it could give I/O time as well as process time.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but apparently timeit doesn't work on current Windows anymore, and the Powershell "Measure-Command" only gives total time, the file information seems gone.